Aldol reaction with KOH and methanol doesn't work as intended, rather works with NaOH and ethanol
I was carrying out an aldol reaction of 2'-hydroxyacetophenone and 4-methylthiobenzaldehyde with KOH and methanol; however, there was no reaction after being left overnight. I repeated the process again with heat and reflux and there was still no reaction. When I carried out the reaction with NaOH and ethanol with heat and reflux, it  worked.
Is there any reason for the reaction to not work with KOH and methanol as the reagents?

I think the extra 15 degrees C that is the difference between refluxing in MeOH and EtOH probably makes the difference. Remember that the 2'-hydroxy group is the most acidic site in the starting material and for the reaction to proceed you are having to create a dianion

Thanks for your answer again on this. Would you be able explain why an enolate is not formed?(is this because there is no alpha carbon?) and if you wanted to proceed with the reaction why would you need a dianion? Thanks!

The 2'-hydroxy group has a pK ~9 so deprotonates readily to alcoholic hydroxide. For the aldol to proceed a second deprotoantion has to occur at the Me group forming the enolate anion
